# Using JQuery's .prev( ) to get the contents of a <p> after clicking a link

Tags: jquery

I want to grab the contents of a     < p > right before a link:

```
<p class="copiedText">aaa</p>
<a class="copy-btn" href="#">a copy button</a><br /><br />

<p class="copiedText">ccc</p>
<a class="copy-btn" href="#">a copy button</a><br /><br />
```

and have it copied to the clipboard using [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/).

I have it working for individual links using this JQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.copy-btn').zclip({     
        path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$('p.copiedText').text(),
    });
});
```

But when there are multiple buttons/links all the `<p>`'s contents get copied at once. I'm trying to implement the [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) operator as such:

```
copy:$('p').prev('.copiedText').text()
```

But to no avail. I've implementing prev() in a lot of different ways but with no results.

Am I misunderstanding how prev works? Or am I just botching the implementation?

(I would link to a jsfiddle of it but the click-to-copy functionality isn't working on there)

[edit: ID's to class's, woops']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at their documentation there is a callback for the copy function. This is what you should use to get a dynamic copy value:

```
$(".copy-btn").zclip({
    path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: function(){
        // `this` should be the current a.copy-btn
        return $(this).prev('p.copiedText').text();
    }
});
```

Dimitri's answer may not work correctly because the zclip binds events on the target. So binding additional events in the event callback will a) not work the first click, and b) possibly bind multiple times. For that approach use an `each` instead of a `click`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all IDs should be unique per document. Replace id with class and select `.copiedText` instead of `#copiedText`

Second thing you want to do is attach click handler to all `.copy-btn`:

```
$(".copy-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).zclip({     
        path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$(this).prev('p.copiedText').text(),
    }); 
})
```

Heres edited HTML:

```
<p class="copiedText">aaa</p>
<a class="copy-btn" href="#">a copy button</a><br /><br />

<p class="copiedText">ccc</p>
<a class="copy-btn" href="#">a copy button</a><br /><br />
```

REPLY:

.click is an event, .zclip is a method. You should implement a method call in the event handler:

```
$(".copy-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).zclip({     
        path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$(this).prev('p.copiedText').text(),
    });
});
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aLBCBFwaThank you for your response and this look right, however, I'm having trouble implementing the $(".copy-btn").click with $(".copy-btn").zclip -- I cant seem to figure out how exactly the two are applied. The syntax is getting me. This isn't working: http://pastebin.com/aLBCBFwa

Comment: .click is an event, zclip i don't think is, it looks like a method. So you should implement the method call on click event like shown in the reply above

Comment: I really appreciate your help :] the 'REPLY:' you gave worked like a charm. I was confused on how I should be using (this), didn't think to try it on zclip itself!

Comment: Actually -- this works but only on the second click. I am stuck as to why. You have to click on the 'copy' link twice and before it works.

Comment: It's hard to tell without debugging. Use Firebug or IE's built-in dev tools to set breakpoints in your javascript code and try to follow what's happening when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're creating duplicate id's try using a classes instead.
ID's need to be unique on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('.copy-btn').click(function(){
    some_text = $(this).prev('p').text();
    console.log(some_text);
});​
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/bradleygriffith/KhuAS/